# What would happen if the salt in the oceans disappeared?

Tags: climate, ecology

Based on current understanding of how ecology processes work, what would happen in the short term as well as the long term if the salt in the Earth's oceans disappeared?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As stated in our [help], questions in the form of "What if ... happened?" are not a good fit here, because they are open ended. After getting familiar with what makes a good worldbuilding question, you can edit this one and try to make it fit our scope.

Comment: L.Dutch already explained in his comment why your question was closed - it's too broad. It can be reopened if and when it's edited to narrow down its scope. I expect it was downvoted for the same reason, though I cannot say for certain.

Comment: I see you were redirected here from Earth Sciences. Unfortunately, other SE sites have a habit of dumping their speculative questions here without actually asking us first or considering our scope. I hate seeing people get bounced around Stack Exchange incorrectly like this; it's a waste of everyone's time, not least your own.

Comment: Please read the comments: two users, myself and F1Krazy, have already explained you why the question was closed, and above the question itself you can find a short explanation. Editing the question to ask why it was closed won't take you anywhere. Even worse calling us names.

Comment: Answering in comments doesn't go any good, nor to the poster who won't grasp what we accept as questions here, nor to the community, which will continue to be flooded with poorly conceived questions. Especially in this case where the OP seems adamant in ignoring the received comments and pushing the same edit over and over instead of actually trying at improving the question.